# What is difference between ToUpperInvariant() and ToUpper(new CultureInfo("en-US", false))

Tags: c#, .net

I live in Turkey and I need to capitalize a key in my program. I had to use ToUpper(new CultureInfo("en-US", false)) instead of ToUpper() because this function behaves different in computers that are set to Turkish culture(See below picture). Then i saw there is also culture invariant upper function: ToUpperInvariant().

I searched but i could not find any information difference between these functions. Is there any difference at all?

[image]
[image]

*source:http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html*

Comment: I would imagine that `ToUpperInvariant()` is closer to `ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: i know that ToUpperInvariant() calls ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) but dont know if it is equal to en-US or not.

Comment: "... if it is equal to en-US" - Officially, no. But in practice they are indistinguishable. I would say you should use the Invariant versions.

Comment: If you're uppercasing so you can compare, you might be better off using [the `string.Compare()` overload that accepts `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx#stringsinnet20_topic5)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - that Turkish i/1 stuff is the last area I would use Ordinal on.

Comment: I dont compare i just send the key and my coworker compares both key in java. He used en-us version in java that why i used en-us over CultureInvariant but could not find difference in practice like tr-tr which behaves different.

Comment: @onurdemir Sounds like your coworker should be using an invariant culture instead.  Either way make sure you have plenty of tests on both sides.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Maybe so, but that's exactly what Microsoft say you should do (in the article I linked). Did you look at that article?

Comment: Hm, no, not that article. A good read, but the qualification 'linguistic' will keep haunting people. It's not always clear when you need/want that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToUpper()` is the same as `ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`, 
whereas `ToUpperInvariant()` is the same as `ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, the comments hint that you already figured that out.

So of course there is a difference here - `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` should only be used when not interacting with humans (parsers etc), as it gives a consistent result, whereas `ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) varies quite a lot between computers, servers, etc.

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is an english-inspired culture similar to but is not equal to en-US and is not bound to any country or region, and cannot be customized by users (as explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx)).

As to explicitly answer your question regarding `ToUpper` - yes there are differences. In all of those cases (presented below), `ToUpperInvariant()` is the same `char` as the lowercase source:

```
lc    en-US     Invariant
==    =====     =========

µ     Μ         µ
ı     I         ı
ſ     S         ſ
ǅ     Ǆ         ǅ
ǈ     Ǉ         ǈ
ǋ     Ǌ         ǋ
ǲ     Ǳ         ǲ
ͅ      Ι         ͅ  //  ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅthis one lives in the 4th dimension. 
ς     Σ         ς
ϐ     Β         ϐ
ϑ     Θ         ϑ
ϕ     Φ         ϕ
ϖ     Π         ϖ
ϰ     Κ         ϰ
ϱ     Ρ         ϱ
ϵ     Ε         ϵ
ẛ     Ṡ         ẛ
ι     Ι         ι
```

Comment: Yes, that is explicitly stated. But the MM/dd/yy format gives it away, that is hardly "not bound to any country or region".

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, it sharing one of en-US's more unusual peculiarities rather gives the game away :)

Comment: True... but I am not sure that it would have been a good idea to choose a format which is not present in any of the default cultures.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It sort of is, though: the whole point of `InvariantCulture` is that if the US ever switches to DMY, then `en-US` will be updated to match, and `InvariantCulture` will stick with MDY. Yes, it was initially created as a copy of en-US (effectively), but it won't track changes.

Comment: ISO 8601 format would perhaps have been more sensible as the standard format of almost every country (even if the conventional format of very view).

Comment: That standard is only pertinent to dates though. Would it be sensible to have one format for dates and something different for sorting, casing, numbers etc? In any case, a bit to late to do anything about it :)

Comment: @Tewr Thanks so much for your last edit. "ı" is used is Turkey and i will continue to use en-US.

Comment: InvariantCulture means it won't change, regardless of what any country does with it's language. Presumably, it also avoids explicitly saying US, and thereby offending anyone who dislikes America.